# Rails.vim alternate file issues - does not detect RSpec

Tags: vim, macvim, rails.vim

I can't seem to get Rails.vim to detect that I don't use `test/unit`, whenever I go into `app/models/model.rb` and issue the `:A` command it I get an error:

> E345: Can't find file "test/unit/model_test.rb" in path

There's no `test/` directory in my tree,

```
-> ls
Gemfile       README.rdoc  app          config.ru    
doc           log          script       tmp
Gemfile.lock  Rakefile     config       db           
lib           public       spec         vendor
```

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me five minutes after asking the question. The problem was that `spec/models/item_spec.rb` didn't exist either (I thought it did), and Rails.vim/MacVim complained about the `test/unit` file as that is the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the plugin [vim-twitch](https://github.com/bodymindarts/vim-twitch) to address the issue of switching between test and production files.